# Xamarin.Forms StackLayout.GestureRecognizers Not Firing Command in iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am running through a [Pluralsight Xamarin.Forms tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=66f13d04-8fef-4756-83ae-55f19620675c) where in the video, tapping the **StackLayout** in iOS opens a detail page for the specific item by firing an ItemTapped command.

For me, the ItemTapped command is not firing for iOS.

Any suggestions on what I am missing ?
Below is the ItemsPage.xaml, ItemsPage.xaml.cs, and ItemsViewModel.cs.
Please let me know if more information is needed, or any feedback :)

*ItemsPage.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:App1.Models"  
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <!--
      x:DataType enables compiled bindings for better performance and compile time validation of binding expressions.
      https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings
    -->
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16"
                            InputTransparent="True"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" 
                            InputTransparent="True"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

*ItemsPage.xaml.cs*

```
using App1.Models;
using App1.ViewModels;
using App1.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App1.Views
{
    public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemsViewModel _viewModel;

        public ItemsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = _viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            _viewModel.OnAppearing();
        }
    }
}
```

*ItemsViewModel.cs*

```
using App1.Models;
using App1.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private Item _selectedItem;

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
        public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
        public Command<Item> ItemTapped { get; }

        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Browse";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            ItemTapped = new Command<Item>(OnItemSelected);

            AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        public void OnAppearing()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            SelectedItem = null;
        }

        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
                OnItemSelected(value);
            }
        }

        private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NewItemPage));
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `ItemsPage.xaml.cs`. Does its constructor contain something like `BindingContext = new ItemsViewModel();`? And look in VS Debug Output pane - any warnings about missing Bindings?

Comment: Added that file to the question, no warnings in the debug output pane

Comment: I test your code it works fine , `OnItemSelected` method triggers as expected . I test on `iPhone13,iOS15.2` with  latest `Xamarin.Forms(5.0.0.2291)` , what's the version on your side ? And If possible would you mind sharing us a basic project to reproduce the issue ?